# if conditions inside where sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying this logic not sure what am missing in this case

```
select * 
  from table1 t1 
       join table2 t2 on t1.column1=t2.column1
 where t1.column1 between 1 and 10 if t2.column2='value1' 
   and t1.column1 between 11 and 20 if t2.column2='value2'
```

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect.  The `join` needs `on` condition(s), and there is no`if` in SQL.  You need to provide more information about the `join` before anyone can help you.

Comment: the join is on the first column, and not sure what to use instead of if

Comment: It is also not clear what you are trying to do with like. The way you have it now requires an exact match, just as if you used =. LIKE usually includes a pattern, so if you want to match values that begin with 'value1', you'd do
LIKE  'value1%'  

EDIT: And you've now edited your code to remove LIKE, so never mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a case when aproach

> ```
> CREATE tABLE table2(column1 int, column2 varchar(10))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table2 VALUEs(1,'value1'),(2,'value1'),(13,'value2'),(44,'value2')
> ```

> ```
> CREATE tABLE table1(column1 int)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1),(2),(13),(44)
> ```

> ```
> select * 
>   from table1 t1 
>        join table2 t2 on t1.column1=t2.column1
>  where 
>  CASE WHEN t1.column1 between 1 and 10 AND t2.column2 like 'value1' THEN TRUE
>   WHEN t1.column1 between 11 and 20 AND t2.column2 like 'value2' THEN TRUE
>  ELSE FALSE END
> ```

> ```
> column1 | column1 | column2
> ------: | ------: | :------
>       1 |       1 | value1 
>       2 |       2 | value1 
>      13 |      13 | value2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=3c75188ba73a9500c99895887ee87272)*

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've left out key details, like the ON for the JOIN and the wildcard for the LIKE, in the interest of simplicity.

```
select * 
  from table1 t1 
       join table2 t2 
 where (t1.column1 between 1 and 10 and t2.column2 like 'value1')
   or (t1.column1 between 11 and 20 and t2.column2 like 'value2')
```

Comment: didn't get any result since i'm trying to to use the second condition (t2.column2 like 'value1') to apply the first filter.
it returned an empty table, it should be getting the rows folling those conditions

Comment: I set up an SQLFiddle and this answer (with the changes to your original code) works fine.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8f9b3/1